# $ sign after each line in files(UNIX OS)

Tags: unix, vim

I am new to vim editor and based on general reading from different forums, I was trying to customize vim by updating the .vimrc file to look something like this:

```
syntax on
set incsearch
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set wildmode = list
```

that gives me a whole set of functionality I need. However, after having saved this content to .vimrc, suddenly all my files started to show $ as the ending character after each line.

i.e. Now even the .vimrc file looks like:

```
syntax on$
set incsearch$
set ignorecase$
set smartcase$
set wildmode = list$
```

and unfortunately I am not able to delete them in the editor. Are there any comments on how to get rid of these '$' signs? Has anyone else encountered this problem before?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The line `set wildmode = list` is wrong, it should be `set wildmode=list` no spaces.

The line as it is queries the `wildmode` option and sets the boolean `list` option

Comment: @Vinayak Agarwal: Then don't forget to mark the answer as correct.

Comment: I know..I am trying to..It says I will have to wait for 10 minutes before I can accept this as a correct answer..

Answer (score 0):

It’s because you said `set list`.

Answer (score 0):

Go check for init.vim file.
For me that file was at **/home/user/.config/nvim/init.vim**
And it was turn on "See invisible characters":

```
set list listchars=tab:>\ ,trial:+,eol:&
```

Delete or comment the line.